# How to strike out an url?

Tags: strikeout

I am trying to strike out a long url, but it seems that I only can either break the url or strike it out, but not both.

I would like to do something like this:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ulem}
\sout{\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}}

but it does not break the url

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide an MWE which shows what you have tried and where you are having problems. Thanks.

Comment: @close voters: Please allow some more time for Peter to improve the question before voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 3):

This simulates the `url` package by recursively breaking the input character by character, striking it out (in `\ttfamily`), applying `\penalty0` to allow linebreaks.  The strikeout is a modification to the `censor` package.

In this EDITED implementation, the characters `/`, `-`, and `\_` can serve as linebreak points. (In the original implementation at the end of this post, any character in the `\souturl` argument could serve as a linebreak point)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{censor}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\censorruleheight=.1ex %THICKNESS OF CENSOR RULE
\newlength\nextcharwidth
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@cenword[1]{%
  \setlength{\nextcharwidth}{\widthof{#1}}%
  \censorrule{\nextcharwidth}%
  \kern -\nextcharwidth%
  #1}
\makeatother
\newcommand\souturl[1]{\bgroup\ttfamily%
  \censorruledepth=.55ex\souturlhelp#1\relax\relax\egroup}
\def\souturlhelp#1#2\relax{%
  \censor{#1}%
  \ifx#1/\penalty0\else%
    \ifx#1-\penalty0\else%
      \ifx#1\_\penalty0\else%
  \fi\fi\fi%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\souturlhelp#2\relax\fi}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\souturl{%
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224354/how-to-strike-out-an-url\_xyz%
}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

ORIGINAL SOLUTION that allows any character as a linebreak point

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{censor}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\censorruleheight=.1ex %THICKNESS OF CENSOR RULE
\newlength\nextcharwidth
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@cenword[1]{%
  \setlength{\nextcharwidth}{\widthof{#1}}%
  \censorrule{\nextcharwidth}%
  \kern -\nextcharwidth%
  #1}
\makeatother
\newcommand\souturl[1]{\bgroup\ttfamily%
  \censorruledepth=.55ex\soutrefhelp#1\relax\relax\egroup}
\def\soutrefhelp#1#2\relax{%
  \censor{#1}\penalty0\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\soutrefhelp#2\relax\fi}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\souturl{%
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224354/how-to-strike-out-an-url\_xyz%
}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]