# How to wrap text by characters and not words, in a text-box-like environment?

Tags: minipage, mdframed

I want a text box (or something like it) that I can put a long string of text not separated by spaces into. It's something like a license key (so it consists of characters A-Z, a-z, 0-9, underscores, and dashes).

I've looked into using `tabular`, `minipage`, `fbox`, `parbox`, `mdframed`, and I just can't seem to find the behavior I'm looking for (the text extends off the page because their text wrap is looking for spaces and dashes). It's frustrating and disappointing to have done so much research for a task that can be done in Word with a copy/paste...

Is there something I overlooked? Does anyone know a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Take a look at the `seqsplit` package.

Comment: Maybe the `url` package can help.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219445/line-break-in-texttt, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275393/hyphenation-of-long-words-in-twocolumn-template and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331979/is-there-a-good-way-to-write-urls-with-tilde-without-using-url-or-hyperref-packa

Comment: Are you looking for [hyphenation everywhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275093/hyphenation-anywhere)?

Comment: Not hyphenation everywhere, I just want it to wrap without going off-page. `seqsplit` looks promising.

Comment: @Peri461 See the answer to that question. Hyphenation without a visible hyphen character is not really any different from "wrap" in the sense you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I set up a loop to spit out token by token with a `\penalty0` following it (which allows breaks).  I do it in `\ttfamily`, but that can be excised.

EDITED to support underscores.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\autobreak[1]{\bgroup\ttfamily\autobreakhelp#1\relax\relax\egroup}
\def\autobreakhelp#1#2\relax{%
  {\detokenize{#1}}\penalty0\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\autobreakhelp#2\relax\fi}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\autobreak{%
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224354/how-to_allowbreaks-at-any-character%
}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This will work if the inputs are limited to "A-Z, a-z, 0-9, underscores, and dashes", as requested by the OP.  In fact the prohibited characters in the input stream will be `{`, `}` and `%`.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer, this is amazing. I also appreciate the note on prohibited characters.